# Is Google Sheet's XPath Query Following a Certain Standard?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a list of stocks (PH stocks) in Google Spreadsheet wherein I have a column containing the latest price and compare it with my set target price. I have been trying to parse this http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/BPI.xml this afternoon and I have been unable to get the values inside the  tag.

Reading through the XPath documentation, I thought it was only as simple as: `=IMPORTXML("http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/BPI.xml", "//stocks/stock/price/amount")` following the hierarchy of the tree and tracing the tag I need. But it doesn't seem to work. Then I tried `=IMPORTXML("http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/BPI.xml", "//stocks/stock/price/amount/text()")` since what I need is the text inside the tag anyway, but no dice.

Is there a special encoding/standard or format which Google Sheets follow? The only thing I got to work is getting the value of the `symbol` by using `=IMPORTXML("http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/BPI.xml", "//@symbol")` nothing else I try works.

I even tried the generated Xpath from https://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/xpath_generator.html which is: `/stocks[@xmlns="http://phisix-api.appspot.com/phisix-stocks"]/stock[@symbol="BPI"]/price/amount`  but it doesn't work.

Any recommendations?

Comment: The generated XPath is rubbish - in the XDM data model, there will never be an attribute named "xmlns". But it reveals the cause of the problem, which Yitzhak has solved for you.

Answer (score 1):

The XML in question contains a default namespace. It creates a 'problem' for XPath expressions.

Google Sheets (GS) seems to be compatible with **XPath 1.0** only .

If your environment supports **XPath 2.0**, it is possible to use namespace wildcard as follows.

**XPath 2.0**

```
/*:stocks/*:stock/*:price/*:amount/text()
```

**XPath 1.0**

```
/*[local-name()='stocks']/*[local-name()='stock']/*[local-name()='price']/*[local-name()='amount']/text()
```